# How can I start a driver at a specific frame?

Tags: scripting, transforms, drivers

I want to add a rotation driver so I add `#frame / 7` to `Rotation X` in my case, it works great, but I want to it to start a bit later, say at frame $120$. Right now it keeps on spinning from frame $1$.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Make sure you delete the driver first then directly paste the following line into the *Rotation X* field.

```
#frame / 7 if frame > 119 else 0
```

Alternatively you can right click the *Rotation X* field and select *Add Driver*. Then right click again and select *Edit Driver*. Remove all *Input Variables*, select *Expression* as *Type*, and paste `frame / 7 if frame > 119 else 0` into the *Expression* field (without # sign)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want a sudden jerk in your driver, then subtract the starting frame and clamp the value:

top driver: `frame/500 if frame > 30 else 0`

[image]

bottom driver: `max(0,(frame-30)/500)`